# URL re-writing in Flipbuilder

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, laravel-5, base-url

I had requirement to shorten the URL so I did as: 
[from this](https://dittmagasin.no/resources/uploads/releases/zipfiles/kondis_06_2017/)(`https://dittmagasin.no/resources/uploads/releases/zipfiles/kondis_06_2017/`)  to [this](https://dittmagasin.no/kondis/utgivelser/kondis_06_2017)(`https://dittmagasin.no/kondis/utgivelser/kondis_06_2017`) using

```
<base href="/resources/uploads/releases/zipfiles/kondis_06_2017/" />
```

into index.php, and writing a rule into Laravel `.htaccess`, i.e:

```
RewriteRule [a-z]/utgivelser/reis_03_2017/(.*)?$  resources/uploads/releases/zipfiles/reis_03_2017/$1 [NC,L]
```

**Problem:** Whenever I try to "Print" from [this](https://dittmagasin.no/kondis/utgivelser/kondis_06_2017) by clicking on print icon in Chrome. It pops up with "Blank Page". But it works fine in Firefox.
These pdfs were created using [Flipbuilder](https://www.flipbuilder.com/).

 Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks